# Can't copy data inside of callback for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION

Tags: c++, memory-management, libcurl

I ve got some chunks of data going through this function, and I need to save them properly. Unfortunately, memcpy doesn't work as intended, regardless of dynamic/static allocation - memory gets corrupted, and I don't understand why.

```
size_t func(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {
    size_t realsize = nmemb*size;
    WebRequest* webRequest = (WebRequest*)stream;
    char* mem_ptr = (char*)malloc(nmemb*size+1);
    /*char mem_ptr[realsize+1];*/
    memcpy(&mem_ptr, &ptr, realsize);
    mem_ptr[realsize+1] = 0;
    string s(mem_ptr);
    cout << mem_ptr << endl;
    webRequest->addBody(s);
    return nmemb*size;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be making this more complicated than it needs to be. I don't know what your WebRequest looks like since you did not include it in your example, but this is a simple example of appending the data to a `std::string`.

It's worth noting that `memcpy(&mem_ptr, &ptr, realsize);` is incorrect. You already have pointers, you don't need to pass their addresses, but if your end goal is to put the data in a `std::string` you should do that directly as shown below.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Wldap32.lib")

size_t read_callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata)
{
    size_t dataSize = size * nitems;
    std::cout << "Receiving " << dataSize << " bytes.\n";
    if (dataSize)
    {
        std::string& str = *(std::string*)userdata;
        str.append(buffer, dataSize);
    }
    return dataSize;
}

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, read_callback);

    std::string rawData;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &rawData);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
    //To try and make sure our callback is called more than once.        
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1024); 
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

    std::cout << rawData;

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why shouldn't I care about null-termination on this line?
str.append(buffer, dataSize);

Comment: Because that's not how `std::string` works. By passing the length of the data to the append call you've told it how much to copy, and it keeps track of that length. It will take care of null terminating the data after it has been copied, although that's really an implementation detail you don't need to worry about.